# function to not be able to change both the value and the address of the pointer

Tags: c++

How should be the signature of a funtion
in order to not be able able to change
both the value and the address of the passed pointer?

```
void testP(int*& k)
{
    std::cout << "testP addr:" << k << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    int* p = new int(5);
    testP(p);
    delete p;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Like `void testP(const int*const& k)`.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a reference to the pointer? Especially if you should not modify the pointer itself? While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387152/440558) by @JasonLiam show you how to solve the problem, there's just no need to pass by reference to begin with. So it should really be just be enough with `const int*` (or `int const*`). And your example might be a little flawed, as there's seldom any need for pointers to single `int` values.

Comment: you cannot change the address of something. I think you mean the value of the pointer (which is an address) not the address of the poitner itself

Answer (score 0):

> How should be the signature of a funtion in order to not be able able to change both the value and the address of the passed pointer?

You need to make the parameter to be a *reference to a const pointer to a const int* as shown below:

```
//---------vvvvv-----vvvvv----------->added const
void testP(const int*const& k);
{
    //*k = 4;        //NOT ALLOWED
    // k = nullptr ; //NOT ALLOWED
}
```

Note that the parameter `k` in the above declaration will be the same if you change the parameter declaration to `int const* const&`.

Comment: Or `int const* const&`, depending on personal preference... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Haha, yes personal preference :) Added that at the end of my answer.